# System.out.println() printing twice during while-loop

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I created a while-loop to create a menu for my program, it will keep looping until the user types 'Quit' into the console. My problem is that whenever I enter 'Transfer' into the console the if statement runs perfectly but when it goes back to the start of the loop the `System.out.println();` message prints twice instead of once. This doesn't happen with any of the other options.

Code:

```
int x = 0;
while(x != 1) {
    System.out.println("To transfer funds, please type 'Transfer'\n" //Typical message
                + "To list recent transactions, please type 'Recent'\n"
                + "To display account details, please type 'Details'\n"
                + "To quit the application, please type 'Quit'");

    String Option1 = "Transfer"; //Variables
    String Option2 = "Recent"; 
    String Option3 = "Details";
    String Option4 = "Quit";
    String Menu = ConsoleInput.nextLine();

    if (Menu.equals(Option1)) {
            //Statements
    } else if(Menu.equals(Option2)){
            //Statements
    } else if(Menu.equals(Option3)){
            //Statements
    } else if(Menu.equals(Option4)){
            //End statement
            x++;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Some of you are commenting about the increment of x in the last else statement and saying that it should be put outside the else statement. It's there because when the user types 'Quit' into the console it will exit the loop, if it was put outside the else statement then the user won't be able to access the other options.

**EDIT 2 (SOLUTION):** I finally fixed the problem. Turns out it was a scanner statement within the if-statement. I should have shown the full code for you all to see but I thought it was just the if-else-statements themselves.

Comment: Shouldn't the `x++` be outside of the last if?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Also you probably shouldn't be using `int x` as flag to stop. Clearer solution would be something like `boolean stop = false; while (!stop) { ... if (stopConditon) stop=true;}`

Comment: I tried out your example and it looks fine. The problem must be in your "Transfer" statements. Also, have you considered using `break` statements rather than a variable that takes the values 0 or 1? Or is it significant in some other way?

Comment: @lared No. Doing that will terminate the loop

Comment: @lared I think the OP is using `x` as a control-flow variable. (`x++` as a substitute for `break`). Otherwise the "loop" would just exit automatically

Comment: You're right, the variable naming fooled me.

Comment: Seems to be a `\r\n` problem with an orphan newline causing an additional loop until it catches up again probably?

Comment: Could you give an example of output?

Comment: The `x` that is causing so much confusion can be eliminated in favor of `while (true) { /*etc*/ else if(Menu.equals(Option4)) { break; } }` -- as k_g mentioned, the increment is serving the same purpose as a 'break'.

Comment: Quick note -- Java conventions state that variable names are camelCase, not TitleCase. Your `Menu` should be `menu`, your `ConditionX` should be `conditionX`, and `ConsoleInput` should be `consoleInput`.

Comment: Turning your code fragment into a running program, I could find nothing wrong; it does not reproduce the problem you describe. See the SO help center for [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @StephenP It must be only on my end then. I am using Eclipse-Luna and the statement prints twice for some reason. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Several things to look out for:

1. You should probably `Menu.equalsIgnoreCase(Option1)`    etc.
2. YOu should put the increment of `x` right after the while loop. You are never incrementing x unless you type End.

I think you really want something more like

```
private static String[] options = {"Transfer","Recent","Details","Quit"};
private static int C_Transfer = 0;
private static int C_Recent = 1;
private static int C_Details = 2;
private static int C_Quit = 3;
private static int[] optionCase = {C_Transfer, C_Recent, C_Details,C_Quit);
private String menu;
private String message = "To transfer funds, please type 'Transfer'\n" //Typical message
                + "To list recent transactions, please type 'Recent'\n"
                + "To display account details, please type 'Details'\n"
                + "To quit the application, please type 'Quit'"

System.out.println(message);
menu = ConsoleInput.nextLine()
while (!menu.equalsIgnoreCase(options[C_Quit]) {
    int case = -1;
    for (int i=0, i < options.length; i++) {
      if (menu.equalsEgnoreCase(options[i]) {
          case = i;
          break;
      }
      switch (case) 
        case C_Transfer: {
           break;
        } 
        case C_Transfer: {
           break;
        } 
        case C_Transfer: {
           break;
        } 
        case C_Transfer: {
           break;
        }
        default: { 
           System.out.println(message);
        }
        Menu = ConsoleInput.nextLine();
     }
}
```

Comment: "You are never incrementing x unless you type Quit" well, that seems to be the point of looping: if command is "quit" then increase `x` which will make look condition false.

Comment: The OP is using `x++` as a substitute for `break`

Comment: "put the increment of x right after the while loop" would exit automatically

Comment: the loop should end when the user types "Quit" only. The `x++` is totally right where it is!

Comment: @AxelAmthor, "totally right" is a bit of a stretch. As you can see, the variable naming confused a lot of people. If this code is to be maintained by someone else, it would be better served with a `break` statement.

Comment: @k_g Agreed, strange use of an incrementor, an int and a while - loop for a break condition. Introducing a do-until with a boolean or, finally, a kind of state mechanism would be much better. But that's not the topic of this questions.

Comment: Actually the suggested answer does not use an incrementer, instead the directions are printed before going into the loop (and again only if the input is not recognized).

Answer (score 0):

This only happen on Transfer option right? Could you show the code for Transfer options? probably there's instruction to print the message over there, so you got the message printed twice when loop is start over again.

add:
based on your 'transfer code'. It seems the problem is related with missuse of java.util.Scanner but I myself not sure about this utility class. But the modified code below is work for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        java.util.Scanner ConsoleInput=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        String Menu;
        String message="To transfer funds, please type 'Transfer'\n" //Typical message
                + "To list recent transactions, please type 'Recent'\n"
                + "To display account details, please type 'Details'\n"
                + "To quit the application, please type 'Quit'";
        System.out.println(message);
                String Option1 = "Transfer"; //Variables
        String Option2 = "Recent"; 
        String Option3 = "Details";
        String Option4 = "Quit";
        while(!((Menu=ConsoleInput.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase(Option4))){
            if(Menu.equalsIgnoreCase(Option1)){
                System.out.println("You have selected transfer");
                System.out.println("How much would you like to transfer?");
                float deduction;
                float total = 2500;
                deduction = ConsoleInput.nextFloat();
                total = total - deduction;
                System.out.println("£" + total + " left in account. Transaction recorded.");
                //Fileoutput.println(sf.format(date) + " - £" + deduction + " taken from account. £" + total + " left in account.\n");  
                System.out.println(message);
            }else if(Menu.equalsIgnoreCase(Option2)){
                System.out.println("here is your balance...blah, blah, bbla\n");
                System.out.println(message);
            }else if(Menu.equalsIgnoreCase(Option3)){
                System.out.println("here is the details...blah, blah, bbla\n");
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks");
    }
```

Comment: I realize you can't [comment until 50 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), but this *is* a comment, not an *answer*, and should be removed.

Comment: [Here is the Transfer option](http://pastebin.com/PkWb0ZWz) I used PasteBin so you can see it properly.